# Change the class of a button when the button text is certain value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to style a site where I don't have full access. All the buttons on the site use the class 'sitebutton'. What I want to do is change this for certain buttons. These buttons use the same class but have text label 'Upload'.

Does anyone know if it is possible to use jQuery to change the button class, identifying it by its button text?

Comment: Do you want to change only the class where the button has 'upload' text in it ?

Comment: Can you provide the HTML code ?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by don't full access? Do you have the ability to add JavaScript to the page or an external JavaScript file?

Answer (score 3):

Here the solution I guess :

```
$( ".sitebutton:contains('Upload')" ).addClass('upload-button').removeClass('sitebutton');
```

Answer (score 1):

This works
    `$(function(){
        $(".siteButton").each(function(){
            if($(this).text()=='Save'){ // checks the inner text in the button
                $(this).removeClass('siteButton'); // remove old class if required
                $(this).addClass('newClass'); // add new class
            }
        })
    })`

If the buttons are input tags use this
    `$(function(){
        $(".siteButton").each(function(){
            if($(this).val()=='Save'){ // checks value of input with type='button'
                $(this).removeClass('siteButton'); // remove old class if required
                $(this).addClass('newClass'); // add new class
            }
        })
    })`

Answer (score 0):

just use `:contains` pseudoclass

`$('.sitebutton:contains("Upload")').addClass('test');`

this will add the class to button if it contains 'upload' text in it